# why are DATA partitions not consistently reported in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, partition, disk-usage, fdisk, gparted

**Why am I getting inconsistent/conflicting pictures of the DATA partitions that were created in the CentOS 7 installation process when I use `df -T -h`, `parted  ...  print`, and `fdisk -l`?**  In case it matters, used xfs file system because that was the default.

The Background of the process is:

During a recent installation of CentOS 7, I chose Manual Partitioning in the Installation Destination part of the process.  [The tutorial in this link](http://www.tecmint.com/centos-7-installation/) contains screen shots illustrating the installation process, and the screen in the process where the DATA partitions are created is shown below (from the same tutorial).

[image]
<sub>(source: [tecmint.com](http://www.tecmint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CentOS-7-Installation-16-600x450.png))</sub>

In the above screen shot, my installation wizard automatically created a `/home` DATA partition.  I shrunk the auto-created `/home` partition, and created four new 300 GB DATA partitions called `/public`, `/vpn`, `/data`, and `/test` using the screen shown in the screen shot, and I then completed the installation.

---

**`df -T -h` results:**

---

In the resulting installation, typing `df -T -h` results in:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -T -h
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs        50G 1016M   49G   2% /
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G   17M  3.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2               xfs       494M  139M  355M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs       605G   33M  605G   1% /home
/dev/sda1               vfat      200M  9.8M  191M   5% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-01   xfs       280G   33M  280G   1% /public
/dev/mapper/centos-02   xfs       280G   33M  280G   1% /data
/dev/mapper/centos-03   xfs       280G   33M  280G   1% /test
/dev/mapper/centos-00   xfs       280G   33M  280G   1% /vpn
```

---

**`parted ... quit` results:

---

However, parted does not seem to see the four new DATA partitions, as shown below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# parted
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  211MB   210MB   fat16        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      211MB   735MB   524MB   xfs
 3      735MB   1912GB  1911GB
```

---

**`fdisk -l` results:**

---

The `fdisk -l` results seem to be a blend of the `parted` and `df` results shown above, but here treating the four new partitions as a separate category:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic 
 3      1435648   3734071295    1.8T  Microsoft basic 

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-49495fd0-6120-48d9-915a-d88903765021: 1911.1 GB, 1911107354624 bytes, 3732631552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8187 MB, 8187281408 bytes, 15990784 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 649.2 GB, 649223733248 bytes, 1268015104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-00: 300.0 GB, 299997593600 bytes, 585932800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-01: 300.0 GB, 299997593600 bytes, 585932800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-02: 300.0 GB, 299997593600 bytes, 585932800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-03: 300.0 GB, 299997593600 bytes, 585932800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

(parted) quit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you chose to use logical volumes (LVM) rather than partitions.  These are not partitions, and are managed using a different mechanism.

Try using an LVM command like `sudo lvm lvs`.  This should list the logical volumes.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for adding insight.  I am willing to believe your answer.  However, this raises a lot of other questions.  I am ultimately trying to implement multi-level encryption at rest on a CentOS 7 web server.  Are you willing to help me figure out the top-level approach to this question?  Here is the link:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231692/how-do-i-implement-multi-level-encryption-at-rest-in-centos-7